# Framework suggestion for CQRS and EventSourcing

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Are there any other Java frameworks for CQRS and Event Sourcing other than [Axon Framework](http://www.axonframework.org)? I am specifically looking for

1. Java based framework.
2. Must support event sourcing.

Comment: https://www.lagomframework.com/

Comment: any latest update on this topic in 2022?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give [Qi4j](http://qi4j.org) a try.

The SDK provides an EventStore for Domain Events and a way to expose them as Atom feeds easily.

Note that at the time of writing Qi4j 2.0 is not released yet so you'll have to use weekly builds for now.

Moreover documentation is not ready either but [the unit tests code](https://github.com/Qi4j/qi4j-sdk/tree/develop/libraries/eventsourcing/src/test/java/org/qi4j/library/eventsourcing/domain) should get you started.

Comment: Just an update: _"In March 2015, Apache Zest™ was created with the Qi4j™ codebase as the base..."_ - from [here](https://zest.apache.org/java/2.1/)

Answer (score 8):

I just found [JDON](http://en.jdon.com/), an event sourcing framework based on work by Eric Evans of DDD fame and Martin Fowler.

Looks interesting.

Comment: not "by"  should be  based on Eric Evans of DDD fame and Martin Fowler

Comment: jdon.org domain no longer exists with the old content.

Comment: Seems to be http://en.jdon.com/ now

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with an Event Store in Java called [Eventstore2](https://github.com/ks-no/eventstore2).

And building on this Event Store I have created an archetype that gives you an initial Java Web Application called [maven-archetype-eventsourcing](https://github.com/bouvet-openlab/maven-archetype-eventsourcing)

You can read my blog about it - [Get your Event Sourced web application development started with one line using Maven!](http://blogg.bouvet.no/2014/07/08/get-your-event-sourced-web-application-development-started-with-one-line-using-maven/).